# How to require node submodules for a global CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, require

I have a nodejs based global CLI that `requires` some submodules from within itself like so:

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var path = require('path');

var variable1 = require(appRoot + '/lib/one.js');
var variable2 = require(appRoot + '/lib/two.js');
var variable3 = require(appRoot + '/lib/three.js');
var variable4 = require(appRoot + '/lib/four.js');
```

This ordinarily works during development when I `npm link` from the root of CLI project but fails when the package is `npm install -g`; it's unable to find the libs from the local installation of the node_module. Also, notice the '/' here to get to the `path/to/library`, which is unlikely to work on Windows.

Since my users will use the CLI on their projects from directories anywhere on their computer (any OS) I want to use os-agnostic [paths](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) to require the submodules within the CLI.

So I tried the following:

1. Symlinking:

   "scripts": {
   ...
   "postinstall": "npm link --local"
   }

This isn't working on my Mac, yet, but I also read somewhere that symlinking doesn't always work on Windows. Otherwise this would be the cleanest implementation of 'em all. ATM I'm not sure what else is there to it to make it work on Windows.

2. Tried to get to the absolute path of libs within node_module/CLITool with node-app-root-path module like this:

So this is the code I got to last:

```
var variable1 = require(path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename), 'lib', 'one.js'));
var variable2 = require(path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename), 'lib', 'two.js'));
var variable3 = require(path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename), 'lib', 'three.js'));
var variable4 = require(path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename), 'lib', 'four.js'));
```

This does not work, gives me the following error:

1. Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/CLITool/bin/lib/manager.js'

Any clues from experts on how to accomplish this?

I did find a little mention on [node-app-root-path](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path#edge-case-global-clis)'s documentation about this, but whatever I do it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/CLItool/bin/lib/one.js'
```

The problem is the `bin` at the end of path it returns.

Edit-1: Ok. I'm able to pull libs with `__dirname` and `'..'` like so:

```
var variable1 = require(path.join( __dirname, '..', 'lib', 'one.js'));
```

and it works!, but it still makes me cringe because `..` :(